# singleton -- static members unrecognized in the cpp file

Tags: c++, singleton

i am trying to implement singleton on my io class
i decleared two static members in the header file however the cpp does not know them.

```
class InputOutput{
//.h
private:
    System* s;
    static InputOutput* io;
    static pthread_mutex_t lock;
}

//.cpp
InputOutput* InputOutput::getInstance(){
static bool initiallized = false;
if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0){
    cout << "error in initiallize lock" << endl;
}

if(!initiallized){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if(!initiallized){
        io = new InputOutput();
        initiallized = true;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
return io;
```

}

the problem is:
undefined reference to `InputOutput::lock'
undefined reference to`InputOutput::io'

Comment: Static members of the class have to be defined in the .cpp file. They are only declared in the header.

Comment: Are you using c++11? You can improve your signleton with c++11. Check this link http://elvisoric.blogspot.ba/2015/09/singleton-design-pattern.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, You should initialize static members in your .cpp file like below,

```
InputOutput* InputOutput::io = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t InputOutput::lock;
```

**Reason**

Since static members are shared between ALL instances of a class, they have to be defined in one and only one place. If you define them like above in `.h` file, they will be defined in each .cpp file which includes that header file resulting in linking errors.